# parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface graphical layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Often when I try to open xml file on eclipse using graphical layout I occur this problem, and sometimes even this error - 
"parseSdkContent failed java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError".

I tried some solutions:
1) Deleting .android folder
2) Deleting workbench.xmi on .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench 
3) Reopen eclipse

But neither of them works.
Someone can help me with alternative solution?

Comment: I think you  deleted "home/.android" that folder